# How to get user Local name?

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

How to parse or get Local name of user ?

On windows log on screen My username is - Admin, but when I type

```
net user Admin newpass
```

It says there no user admin. When I go to Disk C > Users there wasn't any folder called admin. So admin folder was called otherwise. How I can get/parse this name using CMD

Comment: Try typing `whoami`

Comment: If you type `net user` you will get a list of users.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of Users on the System using **`net user`** command.

The net user command is one of many **`net`** commands which is used to add, remove, and make changes to the user accounts on a computer, all from the Command Prompt.

[image: net user command]

Use commands this way :

```
net user
```

Will list all Users be it built-in or created by you. You will get the name of user you want here.

```
net user Administrator
```

Will give all details of the User `Administrator`. As you can see in above image `admin` is different from `Administrator`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `wmic useraccount` to show all information about the local user and user `where` to search for admin[image]
  this blog will give you [wmic usernameaccount](https://www.windows-commandline.com/wmic-useraccounts/) addtional informations